# Error: useMediaQuery is a client-only hook

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I am trying to to create an app using NextJS 13.4.7 and am using `useMediaQuery` hook to detect if the view is mobile or not.  My component is not a server component, but I keep getting `client-only` hook errors.  Now my client component is a part of server component but from the documentation it seems that it is allowed.  Am I missing something? Below is the code,

```
"use client";

import { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import PageDataContext from "@/contexts/PageDataContext";
import useMediaQuery from "@/hooks/useMediaQuery";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

export default function Header() {
  const content = useContext(PageDataContext);
  const isSmallDevice = useMediaQuery("only screen and (max-width : 991px)");
  const [hideNav, setHideNav] = useState(isSmallDevice);
  const { home: homeContent } = content;
  const { navigation: navigationContent } = content;
  const { name } = homeContent;
  const [firstName, lastName] = name.split(" ");

  const onTheRight = { x: "100%" };
  const inTheCenter = { x: 0 };
  const onTheLeft = { x: "-100%" };

  const transition = { duration: 0.6, ease: "easeInOut" };

  const variants = {
    open: { opacity: 1, x: "0%" },
    closed: { opacity: 0, x: "100%" },
  };
  const toggleSideNav = () => {
    setHideNav(!hideNav);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setHideNav(isSmallDevice);
  }, [isSmallDevice]);

  return (
    <header id="site_header" className="header">
      <div className="header-content clearfix">
        <div className="text-logo">
          <a href="/">
            <div className="logo-symbol">{firstName[0].toUpperCase()}</div>
            <div className="logo-text">
              {firstName} <span>{lastName}</span>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <motion.div
          animate={hideNav ? "closed" : "open"}
          variants={variants}
          style={{
            position: "fixed",
            width: "100%",
            height: "calc(100% - 52px)",
            top: "52px",
            left: "auto",
          }}
        >
          <div className="site-nav">
            <ul className="leven-classic-menu site-main-menu">
              {navigationContent.map((item, idx) => (
                <li className="menu-item" key={"header_key_" + idx}>
                  <a href={item.url}>{item.title}</a>
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </motion.div>
        <a className="menu-toggle mobile-visible" onClick={toggleSideNav}>
          <i className="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}
```

Comment: could you share the error message?

Comment: Did you end up solving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. This is because useMediaQuery renders both server-side and client-side. Even if you give the "use client" directive, if it somehow works where ssr is, this error occurs.

As a solution, you can create a custom hook and use this hook by dynamic import:

**example custom hook:**
import useMediaQuery from "@/hooks/useMediaQuery";

```
const useDevice = () => {
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery("only screen and (max-width : 767px)");
  const isTablet = useMediaQuery(
    "only screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 1024px)"
  );
  const isDesktop = useMediaQuery(
    "only screen and (min-width : 1025px) and (max-width : 2379px)"
  );
  const isDesktopLarge = useMediaQuery("only screen and (min-width : 2380px)");

  return { isMobile, isTablet, isDesktop, isDesktopLarge };
};

export default useDevice;
```

**usage:**

```
"use client";
const useDevice = dynamic(() => import("@/app/hooks/useDevice"), {
  ssr: false
});


export default function Header() {
  const device = useDevice();
  console.log(device?.isDesktop)

  ...

}
```

Comment: Hi, `use client` has no effect inside hooks file like you do.

Comment: Hi, @Melvynx , than you for review. You're right. I need remove "use client" inside hook file. I Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to separate your client component from your server component in the app directory.

By default, a page is a server component.

From what I see in your code, you have opted for `"use client"`, but it would be best for you to create a separate component that includes this code.

---

By the way, the issue lies within your `useMediaQuery` hook. I cannot see the code, but I believe it is not SSR-friendly.

Here is an implementation of the `useMediaQuery` hook:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { useIsomorphicLayoutEffect } from 'usehooks-ts'

type UseMediaQueryOptions = {
  defaultValue?: boolean
  initializeWithValue?: boolean
}

const IS_SERVER = typeof window === 'undefined';

export function useMediaQuery(
  query: string,
  {
    defaultValue = false,
    initializeWithValue = true,
  }: UseMediaQueryOptions = {},
): boolean {
  const getMatches = (query: string): boolean => {
    if (IS_SERVER) {
      return defaultValue
    }
    return window.matchMedia(query).matches
  }

  const [matches, setMatches] = useState<boolean>(() => {
    if (initializeWithValue) {
      return getMatches(query)
    }
    return defaultValue
  })

  function handleChange() {
    setMatches(getMatches(query))
  }

  useIsomorphicLayoutEffect(() => {
    const matchMedia = window.matchMedia(query)

    handleChange()

    if (matchMedia.addListener) {
      matchMedia.addListener(handleChange)
    } else {
      matchMedia.addEventListener('change', handleChange)
    }

    return () => {
      if (matchMedia.removeListener) {
        matchMedia.removeListener(handleChange)
      } else {
        matchMedia.removeEventListener('change', handleChange)
      }
    }
  }, [query])

  return matches
}
```

From: https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-media-query

The hook will not throw any errors.

**Note**: You do not need to use dynamic import to use hooks. You just need to make the hook SSR-friendly by avoiding the use of `window` or `document` before the app is on the client.